# Input has to accept two elements but checks one element condition

Tags: python

My programe needs to have an input with two elements to proceed (an integer and a name) but if someone press the letter 'q' it has to be terminated. So far i manage to do that by pressing q and comma ('q,') but i want to remove the comma. It has to be only the letter q. My code so far is:

```
dic={}
while True:

    am, name=input('ΑΜ, Name: ').split(',')
    if am =='q':
        break
    else:
        AM = int(am)
        dic[AM]=name


    print(dic)

print('Dictionary contents')

for char in sorted(dic):
    print(char, dic[char])
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Check whether the input is q before splitting the string.

Answer (score 0):

As [timgeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3620003/timgeb) pointed out, check first:

```
dic={}
while True:

    user_input = input('ΑΜ, Name: ').lower()
    if user_input == 'q':
        break
    else:
        AM, name = user_input.split(',')
        AM = int(am)
        dic[AM]=name

print(dic)
print('Dictionary contents')
for char in sorted(dic):
    print(char, dic[char])
```